# DB Ownership process error running phoenix test in containerized elixir 1.6.1

Tags: docker, elixir, ecto, drone.io

I have an umbrella project compose by:

- gateway - Phoenix application
- core - business model layer notifications a dedicated app for delivering sms, email, etc… users
- user management, role system, and authentication.

The three components are connected via AMQP, so they can send and receive messages between them.

We are using Docker, and drone.io hosted on google cloud’s kubernetes engine. So, what is happening is that randomly the application raises the following exception while running my tests:

```
{\"status\":\"error\",\"message\":\"%DBConnection.OwnershipError{message: \\\"cannot find ownership process for #PID<0.716.0>.\\\\n\\\\nWhen using ownership, you must manage connections in one\\\\nof the four ways:\\\\n\\\\n* By explicitly checking out a connection\\\\n* By explicitly allowing a spawned process\\\\n* By running the pool in shared mode\\\\n* By using :caller option with allowed process\\\\n\\\\nThe first two options require every new process to explicitly\\\\ncheck a connection out or be allowed by calling checkout or\\\\nallow respectively.\\\\n\\\\nThe third option requires a {:shared, pid} mode to be set.\\\\nIf using shared mode in tests, make sure your tests are not\\\\nasync.\\\\n\\\\nThe fourth option requires [caller: pid] to be used when\\\\nchecking out a connection from the pool. The caller process\\\\nshould already be allowed on a connection.\\\\n\\\\nIf you are reading this error, it means you have not done one\\\\nof the steps above or that the owner process has crashed.\\\\n\\\\nSee Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox docs for more information.\\\"}\",\"code\":0}"
```

It’s a Json since we exchange amqp messages in our tests, for instance:

```
# Given the module FindUserByEmail
def Users.Services.FindUserByEmail do  
    use GenAMQP.Server, event: "find_user_by_email", conn_name: 
        Application.get_env(:gen_amqp, :conn_name)

    alias User.Repo
    alias User.Models.User, as: UserModel

    def execute(payload) do
      %{ "email" => email } = Poison.decode!(payload)

      resp =
          case Repo.get_by(UserModel, email: email) do
              %UserModel{} = user -> %{status: :ok, response: user}
              nil -> ErrorHelper.err(2011)
              true -> ErrorHelper.err(2012)
              {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} -> ViewHelper.translate_errors(changeset)
          end

      {:reply, Poison.encode!(resp)}
  end
end

# and the test
defmodule Users.Services.FindUserByEmailTest do
  use User.ModelCase
  alias GenAMQP.Client

  def execute(payload) do
      resp = Client.call_with_conn(@conn_name, "find_user_by_email", payload)
      data = Poison.decode!(resp, keys: :atoms)

      assert data.status == "ok"
  end
end
```

Following details my .drone.yaml file:

```
pipeline:
unit-tests:
image: bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix:1.6.1
environment:
    RABBITCONN: amqp://user:pass@localhost:0000/unit_testing
    DATABASE_URL: ecto://username:password@postgres/testing
commands:
    - mix local.hex --force && mix local.rebar --force
    - mix deps.get
    - mix compile --force
    - mix test
```

`mix.exs` file in every app contains the following aliases

```
defp aliases do
    [
        "test": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "test"]
    ]
end
```

All ours `model_case` files contain this configuration:

```
setup tags do
    :ok = Sandbox.checkout(User.Repo)

    unless tags[:async] do
        Sandbox.mode(User.Repo, {:shared, self()})
    end

    :ok
end
```

How can I debug this? it only occurs while testing code inside the container. Would the issue be related to container’s resources?

Any tip or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `onwership_timeout` and `timeout` to a large numbers in your `config/tests.exs`

```
config :app_name, User.Repo,
adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: ...,
  password: ...,
  database: ...,
  hostname: ...,
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox,
  timeout: 120_000, # i think the default is 5000
  pool_timeout: 120_000,
  ownership_timeout: 120_000 #i think the default is 5000
```

Comment: Hi @badu, thank you for your answer. I tried, but the issue persists.

Comment: @GeorgeCoffey Try adding the ownership_timeout as option to the checkout  like this ```Sandbox.checkout(User.Repo, [ownership_timeout: 120_000])```

Comment: I just tried, but I had no luck. Nevertheless looks like the timeout is issue, since I receiving following exception in my tests. But I don't know why this exception doesn't break my tests:

`Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.9239.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) owner #PID<0.9242.0> timed out because it owned the connection for longer than 15000ms
`